# .cs file opens when creating an event in the properties tab

Tags: c#, events, visual-studio-2013

I just started in Visual Studio Community 2013 and I am running into an issue I can't resolve. I have looked online to find the answer but maybe I am using the wrong keywords.

I am creating a calculator as a WPF application.

When creating a new event, or I copy an event to another button, the code window opens every time. I would like to know if it is possible to shut this down so I remain in the form (.xaml) window.

This is the code I currently have:

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void value_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me to turn this feature off.

Best regards,

Johan

Comment: how do you create the event? by double clicking the object or by typing it?

Comment: I use different methods to create the event.
I can type it, doubleclick or copy/paste to use the same event from another operator.